# How to remove a database in ydn db

Tags: ydn-db

my issue is I cannot remove a created database. 
This should do it:

```
ydn.db.deleteDatabase('db name')
```

But I get this error:

"r.openDatabase is not a function"

What did I do wrong?

Thank :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, but I cannot verify it on FF using js file from http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html `ydn.db.deleteDatabase` works fine on FF, which does not have websql. `openDatabase` is websql api method.

Which version and platform are you using?

Comment: I use ydn.db-isw-core-qry-dev.js + the newest fire fox.